# Migrating to Visual Studio 2017 has broken my IIS settings

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, iis

I have an ASP.NET MVC website that I built using Visual Studio 2010 and it was working correctly.  I could run the website locally and I could debug it from  Visual Studio 2010.  I installed Visual Studio 2017 and I migrated the project to open it in Visual Studio 2017 and now I get this error when I try to browse the website:

> HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.

I tried re-starting the computer.  I cannot debug the website in either Visual Studio 2010 nor Visual Studio 2017.  Any ideas how to fix this?  I only understand the basics of the settings in IIS so if you try to explain how to do something in IIS please try to "dumb it down".

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint in your controller that is called initially? Like the Home Controller's Index method? Does it hit that breakpoint?

Comment: try checking the AppPool Identity.. did you change your windows password recently?

Comment: Vignesh, I don't know how to do that.  When I open IIS Manager and click on Application Pools node I see about 10 different items listed and I have no idea how they got created or whether my website is using one of them.  I even tried Googling AppPool Identity, but I don't understand what it is telling me.  I could probably spend a few hours studying and then MAYBE I might understand App Pools.  Any other help would be appreciated.(and the password of the account we are using did not change).

Comment: Stack crahed - The start page is Home/Index and when I try to debug in Visual Studio it does not hit a breakpoint at the beginning of that controller method.

Comment: You'd need to first verify that your site is using IIS by looking at the project configuration in VS. Then if it is, see which app pool the site is using in IIS. This information is trivial to find if you just look for it.

Comment: The project properties show "Use Local IIS Server" is selected.  Now what?